# disable two buttons after clicking reject/close

Tags: javascript, button, sweetalert, disable

My task is to be able to disable the approve and return buttons after clicking the reject button. Reject button means closing a project. These are my codes. Can anybody help me figure out how to disable the buttons?[this is what the button looks like.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dlq5Y.png)

```
<div class="text-center ">
    <button class="btn m-1 align-items-center btn-success text-center " id="approve">Approve</button>   
    <button class="btn btn-danger m-1 align-items-center text-center " id="clear" onclick="sweetalertrejects()">Reject</button>
    <button class="btn btn-secondary m-1 align-items-center text-center" id="return">Return</button>       
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
                        <script>
                        function sweetalertrejects(){
                            swal("This button means closing the task. You will not be able to revert this action. Do you wish to continue?", {
                                icon: "info",
                                  buttons: {
                                    cancel: "Cancel",
                                    catch: {
                                      text: "Yes, close this task",
                                      value: "cancel",
                                    },
                                    
                                  },
                                })
                                .then((value) => {
                                  switch (value) {
                                 
                                
                                    case "cancel":
                                      swal("Closed!", "Task has been closed.", "success");
                                      break;
                                 
                                    default:
                                      swal("Task has not been closed.");
                                  }
                                });

                        }
                        </script>
```

Comment: Unfortunately your code is missing some stuff, such as the swal() function/library. And I think your HTML markup is a little off, some extra <div> tags there.

Comment: Hi! the code i included is just a tiny part of a whole code. swal is already included in my library.

Comment: To disable the approve button, document.getElementById("approve").disabled=true;
To enable the approve button, document.getElementById("approve").disabled=false;

Comment: I think you are looking for this ..
document.querySelector('#button').disabled = true;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the buttons by id and disable them as follows:

```
document.getElementById("approve").disabled = true;
document.getElementById("return").disabled = true;
```

Here is whole code

```
function sweetalertrejects(){
swal("This button means closing the task. You will not be able to revert this action. Do you wish to continue?", {
  icon: "info",
  buttons: {
    cancel: "Cancel",
    catch: {
      text: "Yes, close this task",
      value: "cancel",
    },

  },
})
  .then((value) => {
  switch (value) {


    case "cancel":
      swal("Closed!", "Task has been closed.", "success").then(()=>{
      document.getElementById("approve").disabled = true;
      document.getElementById("return").disabled = true;

      });
      break;

    default:
      swal("Task has not been closed.");
  }
});
}
```

Comment: hi! don't know why the comment got deleted. but i need to incorporate database with my codes. when the person clicks the reject button the other buttons should be disabled and on the database it has to show that it closed.

Answer (score 0):

You need to include classname "disable" to the Approve & Return button and your javascript code should look like this:

```
<script>
$('#clear').click(function() {

    swal("This button means closing the task. You will not be able to revert this action. Do you wish to continue?", {   
    icon: "info",
        buttons: {
        cancel: "Cancel",
        catch: {
            text: "Yes, close this task",
            value: "cancel",
        },
        
        },
    })
    .then((value) => {
        if(value){
            $('.disable').attr('disabled','disabled');
            swal("Closed!", "Task has been closed.", "success");
        }else{
            swal("Task has not been closed.");
        }
    });

});
</script>
```